# Fastest way to generate sequential alphanumeric number using SQL and JAVA without offensive words of length 4

Tags: java, math, sequential, auto-generate, alphanumeric

By offensive words I mean, the vowels can be discarded, hence we are just left with consonants.

Currently I do an atomic operation, auto increment ID field to SQL.

So when my ID crosses **9999**

when SQL returns ID 10,000 it should handle logic in the java code and return the number to the calling function as **B000**

Similarly when I keep calling the function

```
10,001 = B001

10,002 = B002
```

Note: why B000 for 10,000 and not A000 ? remember, I said no vowels.
Eventually when I reach **ZZZZ** , I will just throw and exception

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to not auto increment an integer ID field? Change your ID field from integer to varchar. In the class where all your database operations are done, you could keep an integer instance variable (e.g. called `counter`). Every time you add a record to the table, you increase the counter with one. Next you could write a method that receives the counter and gives back your desired alphanumeric number which you put in the new varchar ID field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This below worked exactly.

```
    public class testSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String str ="B";
            System.out.println(str+Long.toString(getNext()).substring(1));
        }
    }
    
    private static AtomicLong numberGenerator = new AtomicLong(9000L);
    
    public static long getNext() {
        return numberGenerator.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

try and let me know